# How a 1-point set can have positive probability measure?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose I have a program:

```
x := bernoulli()
if (x == true):
  return 0.5
else:
  return uniform-continuous(0,1)
```

If I am not mistaken, the distribution out output of this program says for any $x \neq 0.5$ $P(x) = 0$ and $P(x = 0.5) = 0.5$

My problem is that this distribution has support on the unit interval where any countable set, including of course the singleton set $\{0.5\}$ has measure zero.  But clearly this is not the case - which means presumably that either the Lebesgue measure is the incorrect measure, or its not right to say that this distribution is on $[0,1]$.

How can this point $\{0.5\}$ have positive measure when it is a singleton in a real space?

Comment: A probability measure need not be absolutely continuous w.r.t the Lebesgue measure (i.e, it need not have a density function). So it can have positive mass at a single point, as is the case for the Dirac mass.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is not that it is not continuous, it is that the Lebesgue measure is zero for any single point.

Comment: zenna, that's what I am talking about. A Borel measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb{R}$ is said to be [*absolutely continuous*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures) w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure $\mathrm{Leb}$ if $\mu(A) = 0$ whenever $\mathrm{Leb}(A) = 0$. This property is exactly what you are expecting. But a probability measure need not be absolutely continuous. It can be singular, or even can be a mixture of something absolutely continuous and singular. So even it is possible that the total mass can be concentrated on a single element (as in the Dirac measure).